# Setting window style in PyQT/PySide?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I've been looking for how to do this and I've found places where the subject comes up, but none of the suggestions actually work for me, even though they seem to work out okay for the questioner (they don't even list what to `import`). I ran across `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` but it doesn't seem to work regardless of the import I try (`QtGui.FramelessWindowHint`, `QtCore.FramelessWindowHint`, etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

u need to import  `QtCore`


so the code will look like this : 
 `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

whenever you see `Qt.`something put in mind that they are talking about the Qt class inside QtCore module .

hope this helps